# References to learn about Majorana Zero Modes

Tags: condensed-matter, reference-frames, education, majorana-fermions

I'm a masters student currently trying to learn about Majorana zero modes in condensed matter physics. But so far the references I have checked have been not really useful for learning. I even read Kitaev's paper

> Unpaired Majorana fermions in quantum wires. https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0010440

But I'm having a slightly hard time going through this. Does does anyone know more didactic references? Up to now these two below have been nice

> Topological superconducting phases in one dimension. Felix von Oppen, Yang Peng, Falko Pientka
>
> Majorana Qubits. Fabian Hassler https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.0897

Comment: I like Alicea's [review](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.1293).

Comment: There was also a good edX course at TU Delft about topology, Majoranas and all that jazz a couple of years back. Their material might be available online somewhere.

Comment: @Anyon thank you very much. The materials are indeed online, here's the link just in case someone is curious https://topocondmat.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled across this Master's thesis by Henrik Roising 'Topological Superconductivity and Majorana Fermions' and found it immensely useful and well written:
https://www.duo.uio.no/handle/10852/51429

I also really liked this PhD thesis by Stefan Rex 'Electric and magnetic signatures of boundary states in topological insulators and superconductors':
https://brage.bibsys.no/xmlui/bitstream/handle/11250/2460720/PhD_Stefan%20Rex.pdf?sequence=1

I referred to the above two a lot when learning about Kitaev's chain/ Majorana modes.

Some other good ones comes from Eddy Ardonne's students: http://staff.fysik.su.se/~ardonne/events.html
I liked  Christian Spånslätt and Nikolaos Palaiodimopoulos Licentiate and Master's thesis respectively (because those are the only two I read).

I don't know any of these people I just google a lot.